# How can I create SSL handshake using BouncyCastle APIs

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle

I have a java code that uses the default java libraries to create ssl handshake with a given domain name.

```
public class SimpleSSL {

    public static void main(String args []) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        SSLSocket socket=null;
        SSLSocketFactory factory=null;
        factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();

        //NOTE: put the ssl domain name e.g. "abc.com"
        String host="";
        int port=443;
        socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port); //add the domain name that you want to scan here         
        socket.startHandshake(); // start the handshake
        System.out.println("Handshake Done");

    }//end main

}
```

I need to make the ssl handshake using bouncy castle APIs. I need to change the set of cipher suites so I want to make my ssl handshake with a specific cipher (that the default java library does not support). I also want to extract some variables from the SSL certificate. In default java I was able to do this simply. But now I am lost!!

**UPDATE:**
**MY Questions:**
What is the class name that I can use to define an SSL socket and X509 certificate?

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html ?

Comment: Which one is for creating ssl socket?

Comment: What you're looking for is most likely [the TlsClientProtocol class](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/TlsClientProtocol.html).